# How to compare a char and escape terminal escape sequence

Tags: haskell, syntax

If I have something like this:

```
main :: IO ()                    
main = do                        
    hSetBuffering stdin NoBuffering
    c <- getChar
```

How would I go about comparing c to see if I got an escape sequence like the arrow keys or ctrl plus a key.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can look up the expected sequences using the *terminfo* database.

See the module [System.Terminfo.Keys](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/terminfo-0.4.0.2/docs/System-Console-Terminfo-Keys.html).

For example:

```
Prelude System.Console.Terminfo> t <- setupTermFromEnv 
Prelude System.Console.Terminfo> getCapability t keyLeft
Just "\ESCOD"
```

As far as the control characters, those will just appear as ASCII controls:

```
Prelude> getChar -- pressing control L
'\f'
Prelude> '\f' == '\^L'
True
```

You might like better to use a more complete library for interacting with the terminal like [vty](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/vty).

Comment: Huh, I never new about that '\^L' syntax. The [Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch2.html#x7-200002.6) is surprisingly quiet about what it means!